# SELECT IF in SQL with multiple criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

I've used a SELECT statement to return these columns, but I need to exclude some rows if they meet a certain criteria.

1. Only return rows with Country of CN or JP
2. For both countries CN & JP, exclude rows with Place "I"
3. If Country is CN, exclude rows with Code "R"
4. If Country is JP, exclude rows with Reason "Z"

Expected result:

[image]

Should I be using an IF statement and nest a bunch of arguments in it? I'm sorry if this has been posted before (or something similar). I wasn't really sure how to Google this and I've tried a few different ways, but didn't see the answer I was looking for. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE
    Place != 'I'
    AND (
        (Country = 'CN' AND Code != 'R')
        OR
        (Country = 'JP' AND Reason != 'Z')
    )
```

Comment: In sql server `"` double quote mean column names, you want `'` single quote for string.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
    Place,
    Code,
    Reason,
    Country
FROM your_tab
WHERE 
  (Country = 'CN' AND Place <> 'I' AND Code <> 'R')
  OR
  (Country = 'JP' AND Place <> 'I' AND Reason <> 'Z')
```